# packing problem of semicircles into rectangle

Tags: algorithms, computational-geometry, packing-problem

I have problem. How can I get the maximum amount of semicircles (for example radius $35\;mm$) into rectangle $(485\times 185\:mm)$.

I found many articles about packing of circles but nothing about semicircles.

Do you have any advice, web, tool, software which can help me?

Thanks Jamess